# Делаю директиву

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, css-animation

Делаю директиву которая должна слушать ивент наведении мышки на элемент и если мышка наведена и не шевелиться 5 сек должна присвоить элементу класс moved который будет делать анимацию... подскажите что делаю не так?

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from "@angular/core";


@Directive({
    selector: '[appMove]'
})

export class MoveDirective{

    @HostBinding('class.moved') isMoved = false;

    @HostListener('mousemove') onMouseMove(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            @HostListener('mouseenter') onmouseenter () {
                this.isMoved = true;
            }
            @HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseleave () {
                this.isMoved = false;
            }
        }, 5000)

    }
}
```

CSS:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes moved {
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(9px);
    transform: translateX(9px);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-9px);
    transform: translateX(-9px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(6px);
    transform: translateX(6px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px);
    transform: translateX(-6px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moved {
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(9px);
    transform: translateX(9px);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-9px);
    transform: translateX(-9px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(6px);
    transform: translateX(6px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px);
    transform: translateX(-6px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.moved:hover{
  -webkit-animation: swing 0.6s ease;
  animation: swing 0.6s ease;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   box-shadow:         0px 1px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
   transform: scale(1.05);
   z-index: 10;
   transition: .5s all;
}
```

Comment: подписки на mouseenter/mouseleave неверно сделаны. Ты пытаешься определить их так же как и Mousemove, но при этом делаешь это внутри функции setTimeout - не надо так

Comment: а как сделать лучше?

Comment: объявить эти поля как поля, в общем пока mousemove вообще убери

Comment: а как сделать задержку в 5 сек?

Comment: Задержку перед чем?

Comment: Делаю директиву которая должна слушать ивент наведении мышки на элемент и если мышка наведена и не шевелиться 5 сек должна присвоить элементу класс moved который будет делать анимацию, а если мышь возобновляет движение убирать анимацию

Comment: Сниппеты предназначены для кода, который _можно запустить_. Css таким не является, поэтому его надо оформлять как  блок кода.

Answer (score 1):

В текущем коде идет ошибочная попытка определить поля класса внутри коллбэка функции `setTimeout`.

Вместо этого их нужно сделать такими же полями как и `onMouseMove`.

Далее задача сводится к тому, чтобы по событию `mouseenter` запустить таймер, по истечении которого присвоить полю `isMoved` значение `true`

по событию `mouseleave` - остановить таймер и присвоить полю `isMoved` значение `false`

по событию `mousemove` - перезапустить таймер, и *опционально* присвоить полю `isMoved` значение `false`.

Как это может выглядеть в коде:

```
export class MoveDirective{
    private timerId:number;
    @HostBinding('class.moved') isMoved = false;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onmouseenter () {
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        this.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isMoved = true
        }, 5000)
    }
    @HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseleave () {
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        this.isMoved = false;
    }
    @HostListener('mousemove') onMouseMove(){
        clearTimeout(this.timerId);
        this.isMoved = false; // если при движении надо сбросить класс
        this.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isMoved = true
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает такой вариан... может что то по стилях не так прописала

Comment: @Анна, конкретно не работает?

Comment: я вешаю эту директиву на элемент которому она предназначена, но ничего не происходит и никаких ошибок не выводит

Comment: @Анна, поправил код